# Regressing confounding variables out of `x` or `y` before plotting in Seaborn?

Tags: seaborn

`regplot` in seaborn provides the arguments:

```
{x,y}_partial : strings
  Confounding variables to regress out of the ``x`` or ``y`` variables
  before plotting.
```

My question is: *When* it is motivated to regress out x, y or both?

And – what does this operation mean formally (in terms of equations)?

Any pointers on where to find a reference on this procedure would be invaluable.

Comment: Probably relevant here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117840/how-to-regress-out-some-variables